# Why should I install vim via brew when I already have vim preinstalled on my mac?

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I've read multiple topics about using vim on mac and almost all of it suggests me to use the install vim via homebrew:

```
brew install vim
```

However, vim is already preinstalled on my mac as I can easily access through terminal. So why does everyone install vim through brew when they already have it preinstalled?

And should I install vim via brew or just use the preinstalled one?

Any answers would help, thank you so much.

Comment: Great answer by romainl - in addition to _or_ instead of `brew install vim` you can get [MacVim](https://macvim.org/). I like having both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unix-like systems that come with Vim by default do so only because they "need" a `ex` command and a `vi` command for [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compatibility and Vim, a well maintained, modern, and pretty faithful `vi` clone, happens to have a relative permissive licence that makes it easy to include.

But size matters. Since it is possible to build Vim with or without a number of features, the default Vim, if any, is always a "tiny", "small", or "normal" version, built with varying subsets of features.

Therefore, the problem is the same on every system that comes with Vim by default: if the user needs features that are not included in the default build, they must get another one and `$ brew install vim` is **one** way to do it on macOS.

Here are a few potentially useful things that are missing from the default Vim on macOS:

- Python support,
- `:help 'langmap'` and `:help 'keymap'`,
- clipboard support,
- etc.

with Python and clipboard being the most common reasons, across systems.

Of course, there is no point installing an alternative Vim if you are satisfied with `/usr/bin/vim`.

Comment: So if I install neovim or iterm2, do i still have to install vim via brew?

Comment: Those things are completely unrelated.